# How comes 2 in my multidimensional array merge?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to merge the duplicate values of a key in mutlidimensional array.

```
$subjects = array(
       array(
           'class' => 'one',
           'sub' => 'music',
       ),
           array(
           'class' => 'one',
           'sub' => array( 'social', 'health', 'science' ),
       ),
          array(
           'class' => 'two',
           'sub' => 'music',
       ),
           
           array(
           'class' => 'one',
           'sub' => 'math',
       )    
    );
```

In the above, I'll need to find the common class and merge their sub into an array. So, the expected output is like:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [class] => one
                [sub] => array( 'music', 'social', 'health', 'science', 'math' )
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [class] => two
                [sub] => music
            )
    
    )
```

I'm trying to acheive that result, but I'm getting `2` out of nowhere.

```
    $class_sub = array();
    $result = array();
    
    foreach( $subjects as $sub ) {
        if ( ! isset( $class_sub[ $sub['class'] ] ) ) {
            $class_sub[ $sub['class'] ] = $sub['sub'];
        } else {
            if ( is_array( $class_sub[ $sub['class'] ] ) ) {
                $new = array_push( $class_sub[ $sub['class'] ], $sub['sub'] );
            } else {
                $new[] = $sub['sub'];
            }
            
            $class_sub[ $sub['class'] ] = $new;
        }
    }
    
    foreach( $class_sub as $class => $sub ) {
        $result[] = array(
            'class' => $class,
            'sub' => $sub
        );
    }
    
echo "<pre>"; print_r( $result ); echo "</pre>";
```

Here I'm getting `2` as sub:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [class] => one
                [sub] => 2
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [class] => two
                [sub] => music
            )
    
    )
```

How comes `2` and how do I achevive the desired result instead? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_push`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push) returns the number of elements in the new array, not the changed array, which is why you are getting `2` in your output. That is not your only issue though as you need to take into account the fact that `$sub` can also be an array, in which case using `array_push` will give you an array of arrays in the output. Instead, use [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
if ( is_array( $class_sub[ $sub['class'] ] ) ) {
    $new = array_merge( $class_sub[ $sub['class'] ], is_array($sub['sub']) ?  $sub['sub'] : array($sub['sub']));
} else {
    $new = array_merge( array($class_sub[ $sub['class'] ]),  is_array($sub['sub']) ?  $sub['sub'] : array($sub['sub']));
}
```

Output for your sample data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [class] => one
            [sub] => Array
                (
                    [0] => music
                    [1] => social
                    [2] => health
                    [3] => science
                    [4] => math
                )    
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [class] => two
            [sub] => music
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/hL7RH)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using [`array_push`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) incorrectly. The function returns the **number of elements in the array**, not the array itself - the items get added to the array in the first parameter, i.e. `$class_sub[ $sub['class'] ]`

You have this in your code:

```
if ( is_array( $class_sub[ $sub['class'] ] ) ) {
    $new = array_push( $class_sub[ $sub['class'] ], $sub['sub'] );
} else {
    $new[] = $sub['sub'];
}
$class_sub[ $sub['class'] ] = $new;
```

What's happening here is that the arrays are getting added together, and then the *count* of the array items (`$new`) is added to `$class_sub[ $sub['class'] ]`.

Try this instead - this will not overwrite `$class_sub[ $sub['class'] ]` and it uses array_merge to add the arrays together (this replaces the whole `foreach( $subjects as $sub )` block, not just the code above):

```
foreach( $subjects as $sub ) {
    /* prepare subjects as an array */
    if ( is_array( $sub['sub'] ) )  $subjects = $sub['sub'];
    else                            $subjects = array($sub['sub']);

    if ( ! isset( $class_sub[ $sub['class'] ] ) )
        /* if this is the first subject for this class, there is no array to merge with */
        $class_sub[ $sub['class'] ] = $subjects; 
    else 
        /* We know both class and subject are arrays so we can merge them */
        $class_sub[$sub['class']] = array_merge( $class_sub[ $sub['class'] ], $subjects);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Out of curiosity I wrote my own version of your function. So, this is *not* a direct answer to your question but, maybe, still of interest to someone else here who is trying to "merge" an array in the way you specified it.

```
function amerge($arr){
  foreach ($arr as $e){
     $sub=is_array($e["sub"])?$e["sub"]:array($e["sub"]);
     foreach ($sub as $s) $p[$e["class"]][$s]=1;
   }
  $classes=array_keys($p);
  foreach ($classes as $c) 
  $out[]=array("class"=>$c,"sub"=>array_keys($p[$c]));
  return $out;
}
```

For a demo click here: https://rextester.com/QKULS37967